# Functional Motivation

Tags: meaning

I am writing an internship type application and they mention *Functional Motivation*:

```
Functional Motivation - please detail how you 
a) embody this competence
b) give a practical of example of where you have demonstrated this
```

However I am not sure what this actually means, what is the *functional*?

Comment: I can think of a couple of different ways to interpret it. No idea which applies in this context, and the sub-questions give no hint. Sorry, but it's gobbledegook.

Comment: I agree that it is gobbledegook, but what I suspect it means is that you are applying for an internship that requires one or more skills and you are being asked to show whether you have those skills.

Comment: I'd assume that this term, which I agree falls into the category of "gobbledegook" for normal speech, is likely to be relevant to the field in which you are seeking an internship.